# Error using Selenium Chrome Webdriver with python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

hi im using chrome driver but i cant fix this error

mycode:

```
options = Options()
        
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        self.site = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
        
        
        self.site.get("https://sgite.com/en/site/")
```

error:
[23468:14696:1004/232130.459:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(228)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[23468:14696:1004/232130.468:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(231)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[23468:14696:1004/232130.514:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(234)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[23468:14696:1004/232130.588:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(238)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.

Comment: Please post code and errors as plain text.  Image links just make it harder for people to help you.

Comment: im sorry eddited

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using Selenium with Python then add these extra options into your Selenium code-

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: how to do same on JavaScript?

Comment: Where are you adding the path to the webdriver. E.g. PATH= "C:/browserDrivers/chromeDriver.exe"
I use this and pass in the path as well.  Don't you need that?

Comment: @Dale You don't need to mention the path in your python code if you keep `chromedriver.exe` into `C:\Windows\System32`.

Answer (score 4):

This same thing worked for me like the answer above me.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://something.com/login')
driver.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly" for Python

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The below code is tested and works like a charm.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Javascript users, the solution is:

```
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
const options = new chrome.Options()
options.excludeSwitches(['enable-logging'])
const driver = new Builder()
   .forBrowser('chrome')
   .setChromeOptions(options)
   .build()
```